# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in existing class in android

Tags: android

Error log is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.service.SmartManager$BackgroundHandlerThread
    at com.test.service.SmartManager.<init>(SmartManager.java:107)
    at com.test.service.LiveUSdkService.onCreate(LiveUSdkService.java:82)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But this class defined as inner static class

My class here

```
public class SmartManager {
    /**
        Varibale initialization
    **/

    static class BackgroundHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {
        Handler mHandler = null;

        BackgroundHandlerThread() {
            super("BackgroundHandlerThread");
            start();
            mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());
        }

        void runInBackground(Runnable runnable) {
            mHandler.post(runnable);
        }
    }

    public SmartManager() {
        /**
        ............
                    */
        mThread = new BackgroundHandlerThread(); // Here i got error like this
        /**
        ............
                    */
    }
    /**
    Rest of the code
    **/
}
```

When i run my application, it gives error like this. But class is defined like shown above. But id dont know why shown like this.

Comment: If you are using large numbers of libraries and multidex is disabled then this occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enable `multidex` to temporarily fix this bug.

Android has a 65k method for libraries that it won't accept large no of files as libraries.

For more refer: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html (Building app over 65k method)

So in your Gradle do something like this...

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: @anaspa will you please give your answer so that other may get the help from your answer.

Comment: I forgot to change buildToolsVersion , after changing this it works
and follow this "http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html "